# Не могу правильно отправить данные post запросом

Tags: python, python-3.x

**http://charge-back.ru/ (Я пытаюсь заполнить форму при помощи скрипта) У меня не хочет высылаться письмо на email-адрес от юр.компании**. При помощи `Wireshark` я тщательно отследил все запросы что и как, какие значение в `post запросах` и т.д, начал сравнивать запрос с Chrome к своему запросу при помощи `requests`. Код:

```
import requests
header = {
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36"
}
params = {
    "Email": "", #мой адрес email
    "custom_U7449": "", # мой телефон
    "custom_U11408" : "от 100 т.р", # данные для отметки 
    "custom_U11469" : "Нет", 
    "custom_U11508" : "нет", 
    "utm_source" : "", 
    "token" : "",
    "utm_medium" : "",
    "utm_campaign" : "",
    "utm_term" : "",
    "utm_content" : "",
    "browser" : "Chrome", 
    "referer" : "",
    "agent" : "Windows+NT+6.3;Win64;+x64",
    "fromsendpage" : "charge-back.ru/index.php",
    "namesource" : "charge-back.ru",
    "ip" : "", #мой IP
    "formid" : "2"

}
con1 = requests.get("http://charge-back.ru/sendpulse/api.php?source=site&type=1&name=&email=ecsdavid863%40gmail.com&_=1509705115007", headers=header) #посылаю запрос который был отображен в Wireshark 
print(con1.status_code, con1.headers)

Con = requests.post("http://charge-back.ru/scripts/form-u7416.php", data=params, headers=header) # сам запрос со всеми значениями
con3 = requests.get("http://charge-back.ru/order2.php", headers=header)
print(con3.status_code, con3.headers)
print(Con.status_code)
print(Con.headers)
```

Все совпадало с оригинальным запросом из `Chrome`, кроме кукисов, почти 100% аналогия запроса из хрома. Я все тщательно отследил, все запросы которые подавались и принимались... В чем-то есть подвох, но я не знаю в чем... Я даже не знаю в чем...  Все запросы `200 статус код`. Помогите пожалуйста.

*Скрины `Wireshark`: Всего во время выполнения действия тоесть регистрации и отправки формы происходит 5 запросов: 3 от клиента (мой пк) 2 от сервера (хост)*
[image: На скрине все 5 запросов][image: Тут скрин где все данные GET запроса, а также кукисов]

На последнем скрине сами `GET` параметры и кукисы.  Все что на скрине можно сказать и предоставлено в скрипте, кроме кукисов и некоторых параметров которые хром настраивает автоматически. Что делать?

Comment: Вы бездумно скопипастили атрибуты из html-кода, что ли?

Comment: @andreymal да, я скопипастил атрибуты проверяя и заменяя на другие атрибуты которые только могли присутствовать у той или иной формы

Comment: Значит почитайте в интернете основы html, как работают формы, по какой логике из всего этого собирается POST-запрос, научитесь пользоваться средствами разработки в вашем браузере и смотреть содержимое отправляемых сайтом запросов

Comment: @andreymal я прочитал теперь все о формах и тегов, переделал свой вопрос, но так и не разобрался как передать данные для подтверждения в классы. Помогите пожалуйста. Я обошел уже все что только можно было.

Comment: Существует очень много причин, по которым запрос может не работать. Посмотрите на содержимое HTTP запроса посылаемого браузером (который "работает"), сравните его с тем, что requests посылает. (к примеру, Chrome позволяет запрос как curl команду скопировать)

Comment: @jfs да, я воспользовался wireshark обновил вопрос, сделал запрос почти на 100% похожий на запрос из Chrome, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: если вы везде 200 OK получаете, то уже только от конкретного сайта зависит. На содержимое ответов от сервера посмотрите: иногда 200 возвращают даже если страница сообщение об ошибке имеет или от ботов так защищаются. "Не посылается почта", если человек буквально не выполнял к вашему сайту запросы, то врядли можно помочь. Есть ли у сайта официальное API? Пробовали куки посылать? Требуется ли javascript выполнять, чтобы параметры запроса составить?

Comment: @jfs куки не посылал, в этом наверное и ошибка, отслеживал все действия javascript не требуется, все делалось на php query, сейчас приложу нужные скрины

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось добавить дополнительные заголовки: `Content-Type` **и подождать 2 минуты, сообщение успешно пришло на почту.**